# discord.js v12 check if user is streaming

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

i'm using discord.js v12 and i wanted to have an PresenceUpdate method for when the user is streaming it says. I found this here but obviously it doesn't work. Is there any updated version to this?

```
    client.on('presenceUpdate', (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const channel = oldMember.guild.channels.find(x => x.name === "channel name");
    if (!channel) return;
        let oldStreamingStatus = oldMember.presence.game ? oldMember.presence.game.streaming : false;
        let newStreamingStatus = newMember.presence.game ? newMember.presence.game.streaming : false;

  if(oldStreamingStatus == newStreamingStatus){
    return;
  }

  if(newStreamingStatus){
    if (newMember.presence.game && newMember.presence.game.name === 'game name' || newMember.presence.game.details.match(/keywords in stream/gi)) {
        channel.send(`${newMember.user}, is live URL: ${newMember.presence.game.url}`);
    return; 
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Please add the work you tried to do and the result of it (If there's an error add it too) in order to let someone help you more easily.

Comment: there is no error, that is literally it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
client.on("presenceUpdate", (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
    if (!newPresence.activities) return false;
    newPresence.activities.forEach(activity => {
        if (activity.type == "STREAMING") {
            console.log(`${newPresence.user.tag} is streaming at ${activity.url}.`);
        };
    });
});
```

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Presence

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Activity

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ActivityType

Comment: How do i add so it only checks a specific user? Thanks a ton

Comment: Add an if statement at the beginning of at the code. `if (newPresence.user.id == "your id) {code}`

Comment: Done it works now, but i have one small problem. I have added so if a specific user is streaming it sends the message to a channel. I placed that code in the if statement where the `console.log` is placed. Basically, it just keeps spamming the message and doesn't only send it once then stops

Comment: @PackOf20 I'm sorry for the delay. I haven't received a notification. You need to check if the `newPresence.guild.id` equals `TextChannel.guild.id`, because `presenceUpdate` is fired for each `GuildMember`. (For example, if you are in 3 guilds with the bot, the `presenceUpdate` event will be fired 3 times, one time for each guild).

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on("voiceStateUpdate", async(oldVoiceState, newVoiceState) => {
    if(newVoiceState.streaming){
        console.log("the user is streaming")
    }
});
```

This has worked for me. PresenceUpdate was not working for streaming.