# Discord.js Bot : presenceUpdate not working for stream (on Discord or Twitch)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm developing a Discord bot with discord.js and I want it to display a `message` when a `member` starts a `stream` (on Discord voice channel or on Twitch). For now, I just want to print in the console the new `presence`.

I use the event listener `presenceUpdate` as given in the [doc](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-presenceUpdate):

```
client.on('presenceUpdate', async (oldPresence, newPresence) => {
  console.log(newPresence);
});
```

My bot has the `Privileged Gateway` Intents activated.

When I start a game (and display with game activity option in my profile), the `presence` shows up in the console:

```
Presence {
  ...
  activities: [
    Activity {
      name: 'my game',
      type: 'PLAYING',
      ...
    }
  ]
}
```

If I go in `voice channel` and stream my game, my status changes to `stream ...`, but the `presence update` doesn't show in console. Same if I start a stream on Twitch.

Discord.js version: 12.5.1

Thank you

Comment: Does [this previously asked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62886871/discord-js-v12-check-if-user-is-streaming) help?

Comment: No, I tried the code in response, it doesn't work (nothing show in console), even if I put a `console.log('presence update')` at the beginning of the callback.

Comment: Do you have `GUILD_PRESENCE` gateway intent enabled ?

Comment: Yes, I have Privilaged Gateway Intents activated in Discord Developer Portal and have intents enabled in the client :

`const intents = new Intents();`
`intents.add(Intents.ALL);`

`const client = new Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION', 'USER'], ws: { intents: intents } });`

(I tried with `intents: [Intents.NON_PRIVILEGED, 'GUILD_PRESENCES', 'GUILD_MEMBERS']` before, but not fix my problem)